# How to animate a progress bar with negatives using Element.animate()

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, dom

I'm attempting to mimic the following widget with HTML/CSS/JavaScript:
https://gyazo.com/76bee875d35b571bd08edbe73ead12cb

The way that I have it set up is the following:

- I have a bar with a background color that has a gradient from red to green which is static.
- I then have two blinders that is supposed to represent the negative space to give the illusion that the colored bars are animating (in reality, the blinders are simply sliding away)

I did it this way because I figured it might be easier instead of trying to animate the bar going in both directions, but now I'm not so sure lol. One requirement that I'm trying to keep is that the animation only deals with `transform` or `opacity` to take advantage of optimizations the browser can do (as described here: https://hacks.mozilla.org/2016/08/animating-like-you-just-dont-care-with-element-animate/)

The example has a few buttons to help test various things. The "Random positive" works great, and is exactly what I want. I haven't quite hooked up the negative yet tho because I'm not sure how to approach the problem of transitioning from positive to negative and vice-versa.

Ideally, when going from a positive to a negative, the right blinder will finish at the middle, and the left blinder will pick up the animation and finish off where it needs to go.

So for example, if the values is initially set to 40%, and the then set to -30%, the right blinder should animate `transform: translateX(40%)` -> `transform: translateX(0%)` and then the left blinder should animate from `transform: translateX(0%)` -> `transform: translateX(-30%)` to expose the red.

Also, the easing should be seamless.

I'm not sure if this is possible with the setup (specifically keeping the easing seamless, since the easing would be per-element, I think, and can't "carry over" to another element?)

Looking for guidance on how I can salvage this to produce the expected results, or if there's a better way to deal with this.

**Note:** *I'm using **jquery** simply for ease with click events and whatnot, but this will eventually be in an application that's not jquery aware.*

**Here's my current attempt:** https://codepen.io/blitzmann/pen/vYLrqEW

```js
let currentPercentageState = 0;

function animate(percentage) {
  var animation = [{
      transform: `translateX(${currentPercentageState}%)`,
      easing: "ease-out"
    },
    {
      transform: `translateX(${percentage}%)`
    }
  ];

  var timing = {
    fill: "forwards",
    duration: 1000
  };

  $(".blind.right")[0].animate(animation, timing);

  // save the new value so that the next iteration has a proper from keyframe
  currentPercentageState = percentage;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".apply").click(function() {
    animate($("#amount").val());
  });

  $(".reset").click(function() {
    animate(0);

  });

  $(".random").click(function() {
    var val = (Math.random() * 2 - 1) * 100;
    $("#amount").val(val);
    animate(val);

  });

  $(".randomPos").click(function() {
    var val = Math.random() * 100;
    $("#amount").val(val);
    animate(val);

  });

  $(".randomNeg").click(function() {
    var val = Math.random() * -100;
    $("#amount").val(val);
    animate(val);
  });

  $(".toggleBlinds").click(function() {
    $(".blind").toggle();
  });

  $(".toggleLeft").click(function() {
    $(".blind.left").toggle();
  });

  $(".toggleRight").click(function() {
    $(".blind.right").toggle();
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  margin: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  width: 800px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, red 50%, green 50%);
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.blind {
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  background-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  min-width: 50%;
}

.blind.right {
  left: 50%;
  border-left: 1px solid white;
  transform-origin: left top;
}

.blind.left {
  border-right: 1px solid white;
  transform-origin: left top;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class='blind right'></div>
  <div class='blind left'></div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<input id="amount" type="number" placeholder="Enter percentage..." value='40' />
<button class="apply">Apply</button>
<button class="random">Random</button>
<button class="randomPos">Random Positive</button>
<button class="randomNeg">Random Negative</button>
<button class="toggleBlinds">Toggle Blinds</button>
<button class="toggleLeft">Toggle L Blind</button>
<button class="toggleRight">Toggle R Blind</button>

<button class="reset" href="#">Reset</button>
```

Comment: do you have any concerns about using the css transition property? Cause the seamless animation between positive/negative blinders can be solved taking advantage of the transition-delay property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: I actually did manage to solve this!

```
let easing = "cubic-bezier(0.5, 1, 0.89, 1)";
let duration = 1000;
let easeReversal = y => 1 - Math.sqrt((y-1)/-1)
```

https://codepen.io/blitzmann/pen/WNrBWpG

I gave it my own cubic-bezier function of which I know the reversal for. The post below and my explanation was based on an easing function using sin() which isn't easily reversible. Not only that, but the built in easing function for `ease-out` doesn't match the sin() one that I had a reference for (I'm not really sure what the build in one is based on). But I realized I could give it my own function that I knew the reversal for, and boom, works like a charm!

This has been a very informative experience for me, I'm glad that I've got a solution that works. I still think I'll dip my toes in the other ideas that I had to see which pans out better in the long term.

---

Historical post:

So, after a few nights of banging my head around on this, I've come to the conclusion that this either isn't possible the way I was thinking about doing it, or if it is possible then the solution is so contrived that it's probably not worth it and I'd be better off developing a new solution (of which I've thought of  one or tow things that I'd like to try).

Please see this jsfiddle for my final "solution" and a post-mortem

https://jsfiddle.net/blitzmann/zc80p1n4/

```js
let currentPercentageState = 0;
let easing = "linear";
let duration = 1000;

function animate(percentage) {
  percentage = parseFloat(percentage);

  // determine if we've crossed the 0 threshold, which would force us to do something else here
  let threshold = currentPercentageState / percentage < 0;
  console.log("Crosses 0: " + threshold);

  if (!threshold && percentage != 0) {
    // determine which blind we're animating
    let blind = percentage < 0 ? "left" : "right";

    $(`.blind.${blind}`)[0].animate(
      [
        {
          transform: `translateX(${currentPercentageState}%)`,
          easing: easing
        },
        {
          transform: `translateX(${percentage}%)`
        }
      ],
      {
        fill: "forwards",
        duration: duration
      }
    );
  } else {
    // this happens when we cross the 0 boundry
    // we'll have to create two animations - one for moving the currently offset blind back to 0, and then another to move the second blind
    let firstBlind = percentage < 0 ? "right" : "left";
    let secondBlind = percentage < 0 ? "left" : "right";
    
    // get total travel distance
    let delta = currentPercentageState - percentage;
    
    // find the percentage of that travel that the first blind is responsible for
    let firstTravel  = currentPercentageState / delta;
    let secondTravel = 1 - firstTravel;

    console.log("delta; total values to travel: ", delta);
    console.log(
      "firstTravel; percentage of the total travel that should be done by the first blind: ",
      firstTravel
    );
    console.log(
      "secondTravel; percentage of the total travel that should be done by the second blind: ",
      secondTravel
    );
    
    // animate the first blind.
    $(`.blind.${firstBlind}`)[0].animate(
      [
        {
          transform: `translateX(${currentPercentageState}%)`,
          easing: easing
        },
        {
          // we go towards the target value instead of 0 since we'll cut the animation short
          transform: `translateX(${percentage}%)`
        }
      ],
      {
        fill: "forwards",
        duration: duration,
        // cut the animation short, this should run the animation to this x value of the easing function
        iterations: firstTravel
      }
    );

    // animate the second blind
    $(`.blind.${secondBlind}`)[0].animate(
      [
        {
          transform: `translateX(${currentPercentageState}%)`,
          easing: easing
        },
        {
          transform: `translateX(${percentage}%)`
        }
      ],
      {
        fill: "forwards",
        duration: duration,
        // start the iteration where the first should have left off. This should put up where the easing function left off
        iterationStart: firstTravel,
        // we only need to carry this aniamtion the rest of the way
        iterations: 1-firstTravel,
        // delay this animation until the first "meets" it
        delay: duration * firstTravel
      }
    );
  }
  // save the new value so that the next iteration has a proper from keyframe
  currentPercentageState = percentage;
}

// the following are just binding set ups for the buttons

$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".apply").click(function () {
    animate($("#amount").val());
  });

  $(".reset").click(function () {
    animate(0);
  });

  $(".random").click(function () {
    var val = (Math.random() * 2 - 1) * 100;
    $("#amount").val(val);
    animate(val);
  });

  $(".randomPos").click(function () {
    var val = Math.random() * 100;
    $("#amount").val(val);
    animate(val);
  });

  $(".randomNeg").click(function () {
    var val = Math.random() * -100;
    $("#amount").val(val);
    animate(val);
  });

  $(".flipSign").click(function () {
    animate(currentPercentageState * -1);
  });

  $(".toggleBlinds").click(function () {
    $(".blind").toggle();
  });

  $(".toggleLeft").click(function () {
    $(".blind.left").toggle();
  });

  $(".toggleRight").click(function () {
    $(".blind.right").toggle();
  });
});

animate(50);
//setTimeout(()=>animate(-100), 1050)

$(function () {
  // Build "dynamic" rulers by adding items
  $(".ruler[data-items]").each(function () {
    var ruler = $(this).empty(),
      len = Number(ruler.attr("data-items")) || 0,
      item = $(document.createElement("li")),
      i;

    for (i = -11; i < len - 11; i++) {
      ruler.append(item.clone().text(i + 1));
    }
  });
  // Change the spacing programatically
  function changeRulerSpacing(spacing) {
    $(".ruler")
      .css("padding-right", spacing)
      .find("li")
      .css("padding-left", spacing);
  }

  changeRulerSpacing("30px");
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  margin: 10px auto 2px;
  height: 10px;
  width: 600px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, red 50%, green 50%);
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.blind {
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  background-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  min-width: 50%;
}

.blind.right {
  left: 50%;
  border-left: 1px solid white;
  transform-origin: left top;  
}

.blind.left {
  border-right: 1px solid white;
  transform-origin: left top;
}

#buttons {
  text-align: center;
}

/* Ruler crap */

.ruler-container {
  text-align: center;
}
.ruler, .ruler li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
}
/* IE6-7 Fix */
.ruler, .ruler li {
    *display: inline;
}
.ruler {
  display:inline-block;
    margin: 0 auto;https://jsfiddle.net/user/login/
    background: lightYellow;
    box-shadow: 0 -1px 1em hsl(60, 60%, 84%) inset;
    border-radius: 2px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    color: #ccc;
    height: 3em;
    padding-right: 1cm;
    white-space: nowrap;
  margin-left: 1px;
}
.ruler li {
    padding-left: 1cm;
    width: 2em;
    margin: .64em -1em -.64em;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px hsl(60, 60%, 84%);
}
.ruler li:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
    height: .64em;
    top: -.64em;
    right: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class='blind right'></div>
  <div class='blind left'></div>
</div>

<div class="ruler-container">
  <ul class="ruler" data-items="21"></ul>
</div>

<div id="buttons">
  <input id="amount" type="number" placeholder="Enter percentage..." value='-80' />
  <button class="apply">Apply</button>
  <button class="random">Random</button>
  <button class="randomPos">Random Positive</button>
  <button class="randomNeg">Random Negative</button>
  <button class="flipSign">Flip Sign</button>
  <button class="toggleBlinds">Toggle Blinds</button>
  <button class="toggleLeft">Toggle L Blind</button>
  <button class="toggleRight">Toggle R Blind</button>

  <button class="reset" href="#">Reset</button>

</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<hr />
<p><strong>A note</strong> on the attempt made here:</p>
<p>
  I was trying to animate a percentage bar that has both positive and negative values. But I set a challenge as well: I wanted to achieve this via animations utilizing only the compositor - which means animating opacity or transform <strong>only</strong> (no color, width, height, position, etc). The ideas presented here were based on the concept of blinds. I have a static element with a background gradient of red to green, then I have two elements that "blind" the user to the background. These blinds, being a simple element, simply slide into and out of place.
</p>
<p>The problem that I ran into was timing the two animations correctly when they switched signage. It's currently working (very well) for linear animation, but as soon as you introduce an easing function it gets wonky. The reason for this is due to the value that I'm using to set the first animation length (iteration, not duration), as well as the second animations start to pick up where the first left off. The value that I was using is the percentage of the total travel distance that each of the blinds will have to do.</p>
<p>So, for example, if you have a value of 50, and go to -80, that's a total travel distance of 130. The first blind travels <code>50 / 130 = ~0.3846</code> of the total distance, and the second blind will travel <code>1 - ~0.3846 = ~0.6154</code> of the total distance.</p>
<p>But, these are not the correct values for the <em>duration</em> of the animation. Instead, these are the percentages of the easing values (the y-axis). To get the duration for these, I would have to find the x value (given the known y value). eg, for an ease-out animation for a value going from 50 to -80, the animation crosses our 0 at ~0.03846, and we would have to solve for x given <code>0.03846 = sin((x * PI) / 2)</code>.</p>
<p>With the help of Wolfram Alpha, I was able to find a few test values this got me much closer to the actual animation, but the blinds always stopped slightly off the mark. I eventually chalked this up to one of two reasons: the fact that the valuess are always going to be approximate and the browser is never going to be 100% accurate, or / and 2) the browser is using a slightly different easing function than I was using for reference. Regardless, being so constrained by the fact that this "animation" relies on two different aniamtions lining up perfectly, I decided to leave this version be and go in a different direction.</p>
<p>
If anyone finds an actual solution to this, please post an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62866844/how-to-animate-a-progress-bar-with-negatives-using-element-animate
</p>
```

Thanks to those that attempted this admittedly tricky problem

Answer (score 1):

I've modified your code. Have a look at the code.

```js
let currentPercentageState = 0;

function animate(percentage) {

  var animation = [{
      transform: `translateX(${currentPercentageState}%)`,
      easing: "ease-out"
    },
    {
      transform: `translateX(${percentage}%)`
    }
  ];

  var timing = {
    fill: "forwards",
    duration: 1000
  };

  if (percentage < 0) {
    $(".blind.right")[0].animate(
      [{
          transform: `translateX(0%)`,
          easing: "ease-out"
        },
        {
          transform: `translateX(0%)`
        }
      ], timing);
    $(".blind.left")[0].animate(animation, timing);

  } else {
    $(".blind.left")[0].animate(
      [{
          transform: `translateX(0%)`,
          easing: "ease-out"
        },
        {
          transform: `translateX(0%)`
        }
      ], timing);
    $(".blind.right")[0].animate(animation, timing);
  }


  // save the new value so that the next iteration has a proper from keyframe
  //currentPercentageState = percentage;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".apply").click(function() {
    animate($("#amount").val());
  });

  $(".reset").click(function() {
    animate(0);

  });

  $(".random").click(function() {
    var val = (Math.random() * 2 - 1) * 100;
    $("#amount").val(val);
    animate(val);

  });

  $(".randomPos").click(function() {
    var val = Math.random() * 100;
    $("#amount").val(val);
    animate(val);

  });

  $(".randomNeg").click(function() {
    var val = Math.random() * -100;
    $("#amount").val(val);
    animate(val);
  });

  $(".toggleBlinds").click(function() {
    $(".blind").toggle();
  });

  $(".toggleLeft").click(function() {
    $(".blind.left").toggle();
  });

  $(".toggleRight").click(function() {
    $(".blind.right").toggle();
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  margin: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  width: 800px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, red 50%, green 50%);
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.blind {
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  background-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  min-width: 50%;
}

.blind.right {
  left: 50%;
  border-left: 1px solid white;
  transform-origin: left top;
}

.blind.left {
  border-right: 1px solid white;
  transform-origin: left top;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class='blind right'></div>
  <div class='blind left'></div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<input id="amount" type="number" placeholder="Enter percentage..." value='40' />
<button class="apply">Apply</button>
<button class="random">Random</button>
<button class="randomPos">Random Positive</button>
<button class="randomNeg">Random Negative</button>
<button class="toggleBlinds">Toggle Blinds</button>
<button class="toggleLeft">Toggle L Blind</button>
<button class="toggleRight">Toggle R Blind</button>

<button class="reset" href="#">Reset</button>
```

Comment: This is resetting the state of things every time a new value is set. This is fairly easy without too much modification (modifying things based on if the value is negative or not). However, the question was more to do with animating from previous to new value smoothly. See the Gyazo link for what I'm trying to emulate. Basically, if it's at 40%, and it gets set to -30%, I don't want the bar to just just instantly pop and start at 0 and go to -30%, but instead I need it to start at 40% and gradually animate towards -30% (within the same easing during, seamless). Hope that clarifies things!

Comment: Oh sorry for the misunderstanding :) Let me try again

Comment: I added the negative or not check because your code was just animating the `.blind.right`. That's why to animate the `.blind.left`, I had to add that check :)

Comment: Yep, I left `.blind.left` alone since I didn't really know how to animate it properly with `.blind.right`. It's pretty easy to animate it by itself, or like what you did by resetting the state between values being set. But, for me at least, it's much more difficult to animate it by "picking up" the animation of the other one if that makes sense. Got to that point and couldn't see a way to do it, so I left it alone :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to animate the things in two steps. The first step is to reset the previous state to initial state(which should be set to 0) and in the second step, you need to run the other animation which will actually move it to the destination state.
In order to achive this you can do,

```
let currentPercentageState = 0;
const animationTiming = 300;

function animate(percentage) {
  let defaultTranformVal = [{
    transform: `translateX(${currentPercentageState}%)`,
    easing: "ease-out"
  }, {transform: `translateX(0%)`}];
  var animation = [{
      transform: `translateX(0%)`,
      easing: "ease-out"
    },{
      transform: `translateX(${percentage}%)`,
      easing: "ease-out"
    }];
  var timing = {
    fill: "forwards",
    duration: animationTiming
  };
  if (percentage < 0) {
    if(currentPercentageState > 0) {
      $(".blind.right")[0].animate(defaultTranformVal, timing); 
      setTimeout(() => {
        $(".blind.left")[0].animate(animation, timing);
      }, animationTiming); 
    } else {
      $(".blind.left")[0].animate(animation, timing);
    }
  }
  if(percentage > 0) {
   if(currentPercentageState < 0) {
    $(".blind.left")[0].animate(defaultTranformVal, timing);
     setTimeout(() => {
       $(".blind.right")[0].animate(animation, timing);
     }, animationTiming);
   } else {
     $(".blind.right")[0].animate(animation, timing);
   }
  }

  // save the new value so that the next iteration has a proper from keyframe
  currentPercentageState = percentage;
}
```

Here, you will see we have two transformations. The first one **defaultTranformVal** will move the **currentPercentageState** to zero and then the other one which will move from 0 to percentage.

You need to handle a couple of conditions here. The first one is if you are running it the first time(means there is no **currentPercentageState**), you don't need to run **defaultTranformVal**. If you have **currentPercentageState** then you need to run **defaultTranformVal** and then run the second animation.

**Note:-** You also need to clear the timeout in order to prevent the memory leak. This can be handle by storing the **setTimout** return value and then when next time it's running clear the previous one with the help of **clearTimeout**.

Here is the updated codepen example:-
https://codepen.io/gauravsoni119/pen/yLeZBmb?editors=0011

Comment: Hey there, thanks for explanation! The example has a few issues with it though - setting it to "Random Negative" multiple times shows an odd positioning bug. Clicking "Random Positive" multiple times shows that it resets to 0 each time before going to value. These are things I can figure out by careful evaluation of the conditions.

Comment: But the biggest issue that I see is that since the animation is broken out into two steps, each of those steps has the same animation duration. The easing function isn't seamless, and I think that is the biggest ??? that I have. I feel like I need to create my own easing function that is calculated by which percentage of easing it's at, and then instead of animating, simply changing the transform property. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: I fixed the issues that you mentioned in the first comment. But I am not sure about your second comment on how to handle the smoothness. Let me try something else that might help in this case.

Comment: Can you try by removing the white border of the two divs? I think that is also adding some impact on the smoothness(visually).

Comment: Going from a positive to a negative still results in two animations with identical duration. If I set the duration to 1s, then the right blind marches towards 0 in 1 second, then the left blind goes to it's value in one second, effectively making the whole thing 2 seconds. On top of that, the easing isn't seemless - each bar has it's own easing being applied. I was looking for a solution where, given a 1 second animation, the right blind may take (for eg).3 seconds and basically use the first 30%of the easing curve, while the second blind animated in .7 seconds using the rest of the curve.

Comment: I've played around with it the last few nights and determined that it's probably not a feasible problem. See my answer for more details :) Thanks for helping out tho!